# Install newest version of thrift via apt-get or another way using ansible?

Tags: thrift, ansible, apt

I'm interested in installing thrift 0.9.2 on my ubuntu system so that I'll have access to the `fullcamel`. It seems like the repository I'm using has only version 0.9.0. I know I could build from sources, but I need an easier-to-automate way to do this, because I need to be able to install this version as an ansible task. Currently, I have the following ansible tasks:

```
- name: Install libthrift-java=0.9.0-1ubuntu1
  apt: name=libthrift-java=0.9.0-1ubuntu1 state=present

- name: Install thrift-compiler=0.9.0-3
  apt: name=thrift-compiler=0.9.0-3 state=present
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install thrift from a newer package, generally you'd probably want to use [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and [Ansible's apt_repository](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_repository_module.html) to add updated repos and packages. However, [it doesn't look like thrift 0.9.2 is available on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=thrift).

Alternately, you can ansibleize [the instructions given for installing Thrift from scratch](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/debian).

Comment: Thrift 0.9.2 is the *forthcoming* release. IOW, not yet released, but planned for near future.

Comment: Its now 2 years later, https://github.com/apache/thrift/releases shows 0.9.3 as a release. Not available via apt-get :(

Comment: @MikeGraf it's been two years and the original asker has yet to ask for clarification or accept an answer :)